# Shell Script Language help in unzip command

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a zip folder named `ISAS01_102013 (issue 296 and 297).zip`.
When I unzipped the directory, it created a directory named `ISAS01_102013 (issue 296 and 297)`.

When tried doing `cd ISAS01_102013 (issue 296 and 297)`, I got an error due to space being in the folder name. How do I export the zip data in a folder name other than `ISAS01_102013 (issue 296 and 297)` e.g. a folder named `/data`. The received folder `"ISAS01_102013 (issue 296 and 297).zip"` is always dynamic.

---

**[EDIT]**

The code:

```
#zip_research is the folder where we place the zip datas got 
#i.e. RSIS01_122014 (Issue 238 to 249).zip, ISAS03_072014 (Issue 19).zip etc 
cd zip_research 
unzip -o *.zip 

#Considering it has only one unzipped folder 
for dir in * 
do 
    cd $dir 
done
```

Error message:

```
error: cd: RSIS01_122014 No such file or directory exists
```

Comment: It's common and trivaial for a programmer. Use `escape character` to do that. http://www.hecticgeek.com/2014/02/spaces-file-names-command-line/

Comment: I tried that it works for this folder ISAS01_102013 (issue 296 and 297) when we know where escape characters are needed but when we don't know the exact file name can't figure out the escape characters as ISAS01_102013 (issue 20) or ISAS01_102013 (issue 2,13,67)

Comment: You should provide your script. Your question is not clear, the space may not be the key point. If your script is correct, @Trevor Hickey  has already solved your problem.

Comment: #zip_research is the folder where we place the zip datas got i.e. RSIS01_122014 (Issue 238 to 249).zip,ISAS03_072014 (Issue 19).zip etc


cd zip_research
unzip -o \*.zip


#Considering it has only one unzipped folder


for dir in *
do
   cd $dir
done

error: cd: RSIS01_122014 No such file or directory exists

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what program you are using to unzip a file, but you should see if there is a command line option to name the extracted data a certain way.  For example:

```
unzip package.zip -d data;
cd data;
```

---

However, spaces contained in a file name are no problem if you escape the spaces in your command.
If you have a directory named `ISAS01_102013 (issue 296 and 297)`,
you can step into that directory using the following command:
 `cd ISAS01_102013\ \(issue\ 296\ and\ 297\)/`

or more simply, wrap the directory name in quotes:

```
cd "ISAS01_102013 (issue 296 and 297)"/
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but with the command the folder name remains the same ISAS01_102013 (issue 296 and 297) I don't want the same name, I want the folder name to be data and the contents inside it to be the contents of ISAS01_102013 (issue 296 and 297) as every time the folder provided changes as ISAS01_102013 (issue 296 and 297),ISAS01_102013 (issue 31) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Originally, I tried `awk` `sed` `cut` on this problem, but I got the same error.
So, I eat my words in the comment, the problem should use a different way to solve.

My solution: (of course the problem have many solutions)

```
#!/bin/bash

# change directory to zip_research
cd zip_research 

# grep zip file in the directory line by line
while read line;
do
    unzip -o "$line";
done <<< "`ls|grep -G '.zip$'`";
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I didn't find the unzipped files in zip_research directory.

Comment: sorry, I test the code on tar file, you can change the command to `unzip -o "$line";` or other unzip command in while loop.